# debian and ssh, connecting problem

Tags: ssh, debian, port-forwarding

Greetings,
I have installed ssh on a fresh debian server machine. For this purpose, I have forwarded the port 22 via the adsl control panel (the connection that my server uses) and set a static ip to the forwarded port by changing the /etc/network/interfaces by the guidance of [this link](http://www.techiecorner.com/486/how-to-setup-static-ip-in-debian/).

Now, I'm trying to connect to my server from another network, which means I use the internet ip of the server inorder to connect yet I fail.

Any idea what can be the reason of this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Not really; you haven't included nearly enough info to make a reasonable guess.  Start by listing all of the IP addresses involved (feel free to anonymize the public IP if that makes you feel better).  Describe the settings you changed on your DSL router.  Run an ssh connection attempt with the `-v` flag and include the output.

I'm sure we'll be able to help you troubleshoot this problem, but you have to give us *something* to go on...

Comment: hello I have my modem routing from 192.168.2.1 as a gateway and I set static ip 192.168.2.2 for my server machine, also forwarded port 22 to 192.168.2.2 via the adsl modem configuration. When I do "# netstat -tulpn | grep :22" at the server machine, it gives me "tcp 0 0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN" I don't see any issue with the server part

Comment: In addition, this is the output of the ssh connection attempt:
uluc@uluc-desktop:~$ ssh 88.xx.xx.xx -v -p 22

OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to 88.xx.xx.xx [88.xx.xx.xx] port 22.

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules on the server that could be dropping packets to port 22?  If you run tcpdump on the server, do you see any ssh packets?  Alternatively, if you run tcpdump on the client, do you see any reply packets?  Can you ssh to the server from another machine on the local network?